# How to use an shared variable between multiple interacting C files?

Tags: c, variables, scope, include, extern

I am trying to declare an variable `x` in a file `demo_f1.c` and use it in two files `demo_f2.c` and `demo_f3.c` having two functions `void f2()` and `void f3()`, respectively.

I have a driver program that uses the variable `x` and both of these functions, but it gives me an error while I try to compile the driver program.

**demo_f1.c**

```
int x=2;
```

**demo_f2.c**

```
#include"C:\TC\BIN\demo_f1.C"

void f2()

{

    extern int x;

    printf("In f2 x:%d\n",x);

}
```

**demo_f3.c**

```
#include"C:\TC\BIN\demo_f1.C"

void f3()

{

    extern int x;

    printf("In f3 x:%d\n",x);

}
```

**Driver.c**

```
#include"stdio.h"
#include"conio.h"
#include"C:\TC\BIN\demo_f1.C"
#include"C:\TC\BIN\demo_f2.C"
#include"C:\TC\BIN\demo_f3.C"
void main()

{

    clrscr();

    printf("In main program,x:%d\n",x);

    f2();

    f3();

    getch();

}
```

The error:

```
Compiling C\TC\BIN\Driver.C:
Error C\TC\BIN\DEMO_F1.C 1: Variable 'x' is initialized more than once
Error C\TC\BIN\DEMO_F1.C 1: Variable 'x' is initialized more than once
```

Why am I getting this error? How can I correct it?

Comment: Why are you #includeing a .c file?

Comment: immibis I know I should #include a .h file generally,but #includeing a .c file also works. No issue with that.

Answer (score 0):

To make your code compile, you simply need to remove `extern int x;` from `f2()` and `f3()`.  For a more complete answer read  [How do I use extern to share variables between source files in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files-in-c) as grahamj42 suggests.

Answer (score 0):

You are including demo_f1.c three times in driver.c, one directly and two indirectly through demo_f2.c and demo_f3.c. In consequence, the compiler finds three times the line "int x=2;"

You can use the mechanism with #ifndef typically used in header files. Make demo_f1.c like this:

```
#ifndef DEMO_F1_C
#define DEMO_F1_C
int x=2;
#endif
```

Alternatively, to avoid including the .c file, you could have:

demo_f1.h

```
#ifndef DEMO_F1_H
#define DEMO_F1_H
extern int x;
#endif
```

demo_f1.c

```
#include "demo_f1.h"
int x = 2;
```

And the other files would include demo_f1.h.